# Separate list elements by theirs property in Python

Tags: python

I have list `p1`:

```
p1 = [
    {'id': 1, 'area': 5},
    {'id': 2, 'area': 6},
    {'id': 3, 'area': 10},
    {'id': 4, 'area': 6},
    {'id': 5, 'area': 6},
    {'id': 6, 'area': 6},
    {'id': 7, 'area': 4},
    {'id': 8, 'area': 4}
]
```

And I need to separate this list by `area` value, like this (`p2`):

```
p2 = {
    4: [
        {'id': 7, 'area': 4},
        {'id': 8, 'area': 4}
    ],
    5: [
        {'id': 1, 'area': 5}
    ],
    6: [
        {'id': 2, 'area': 6},
        {'id': 4, 'area': 6},
        {'id': 5, 'area': 6},
        {'id': 6, 'area': 6}
    ],
    10: [
        {'id': 3, 'area': 10}
    ]
}
```

My solution is:

```
areas = {x['area'] for x in p1}
p2 = {}
for area in areas:
    p2[area] = [x for x in p1 if x['area'] == area]
```

It seems to work, but is there any better and more "pythonic" solution?

Comment: Are you interested in a solution involving pandas?

Comment: @COLDSPEED No, I want it pure :)

Comment: hint: use `pprint` (together with the optional `width` parameter) to get nicely formatted output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `groupby` you get

```
>>> import itertools
>>> f = lambda t: t['area']
>>> {i: list(b) for i, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(p1, key=f), key=f)}
```

Gives

```
{4: [{'area': 4, 'id': 7}, 
     {'area': 4, 'id': 8}],
 5: [{'area': 5, 'id': 1}],
 6: [{'area': 6, 'id': 2},
     {'area': 6, 'id': 4},
     {'area': 6, 'id': 5},
     {'area': 6, 'id': 6}],
 10: [{'area': 10, 'id': 3}]}
```

**edit**: If you don't like using lambdas you can also do, as suggested by bro-grammer

```
>>> import operator
>>> f = operator.itemgetter('area')
```

Comment: Good one. You can also try `operator.itemgetter` instead of lambda.

Comment: why `{i: list(b) for i, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(p1), key=f)}` and `{i: list(b) for i, b in itertools.groupby(p1, key=f)}` produce two different result just  the addition of sorted function is there.In second case `id:2` is not in result @bro-grammer

Comment: `itertools.groupby` collects contagious elements with the same key. By sorting the list you make the similar items contagious.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for i in p1:
    result[i['area']].append(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use one of the grouping idioms. Using a vanilla `dict`:

```
In [15]: p1 = [
    ...:     {'id': 1, 'area': 5},
    ...:     {'id': 2, 'area': 6},
    ...:     {'id': 3, 'area': 10},
    ...:     {'id': 4, 'area': 6},
    ...:     {'id': 5, 'area': 6},
    ...:     {'id': 6, 'area': 6},
    ...:     {'id': 7, 'area': 4},
    ...:     {'id': 8, 'area': 4}
    ...: ]

In [16]: p2 = {}

In [17]: for d in p1:
    ...:     p2.setdefault(d['area'], []).append(d)
    ...:

In [18]: p2
Out[18]:
{4: [{'area': 4, 'id': 7}, {'area': 4, 'id': 8}],
 5: [{'area': 5, 'id': 1}],
 6: [{'area': 6, 'id': 2},
  {'area': 6, 'id': 4},
  {'area': 6, 'id': 5},
  {'area': 6, 'id': 6}],
 10: [{'area': 10, 'id': 3}]}
```

Or more neatly, using a `defaultdict`:

```
In [23]: from collections import defaultdict

In [24]: p2 = defaultdict(list)

In [25]: for d in p1:
    ...:     p2[d['area']].append(d)
    ...:

In [26]: p2
Out[26]:
defaultdict(list,
            {4: [{'area': 4, 'id': 7}, {'area': 4, 'id': 8}],
             5: [{'area': 5, 'id': 1}],
             6: [{'area': 6, 'id': 2},
              {'area': 6, 'id': 4},
              {'area': 6, 'id': 5},
              {'area': 6, 'id': 6}],
             10: [{'area': 10, 'id': 3}]})
```